# Audio html5 on mute event javascript? In MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I need to find some event that fires,when i press mute button.On volumechange works only, when i change volume.

```
  <audio id="volumeController" onvolumechange="changeVolume()"controls>
            <source src="~/Sounds/beep.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
        </audio>
```

also i tried to use onclick and onchange events but instead of current volume,it sends always 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HTML5  there isn't any mute event , when you click on mute and media gets muted it still counted as `volumechange` event .But there is another way that you can discern whether it's a mute or regular volumechage ; you can use `muted` property it gets set to `true` when you mute `false` otherwise

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

audio.addEventListener('volumechange',function(e){
  if(this.muted)
        console.log('Audio muted');
}, false);
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/8w0ppdf4/